# Joining Excel file with CityGML file using FME?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, fme-form, attribute-joins, excel, citygml

I want to join a excel file with a CityGML file with FME.

i want to join the excel file with the geometry of the CityGML file.

all attributes should join this file

which settings should i choose in the feature merger to get it?

in the end i want to put it all together in a ArcGIS geodatabase

Comment: In general for Feature Merger you need requestor features (CityGML) and supplier features (rows of the Excel table) to share a common attribute, an ID, name, address or something else. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

As Detlev mentioned, you need a common attribute between the Excel and CityGML file for the FeatureMerger to join together.

Link your CityGML to the Requestor Port and the Excel file to the Supplier Port. Where it says Join On, choose the common attributes and set the comparison mode to Automatic.  Unless you know that they are strings or numeric fields.

Merge Properties will be Attributes Only.

[image]

It's likely that you'll be okay with the defaults.  However, if you're not getting the correct results, have a look at the **[documentation](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/featuremerger.htm)**.